# Size followed by multiple parameters in C++ inFile.Read

Tags: c++, function, parameters

Can anyone explain the parameters for inFile.Read in C++ ? I've found many examples of the method used with a size followed by a single parameter but, despite it being a simple function, I can not find any documentation that illustrates the method signature.

I've just come across this in someone elses code:

```
inFile.Read(sizeof(float), val1, val2);
```

Could anyone explain the multiple parameters or point me to any proper documentation on this function. I've already googled it and can't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so as the docs for that method only acceptes two parameters. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

Comment: My documentation only shows a single `read` method on `std::basic_stream` that takes just 2 arguments: 
`basic_istream& read( char_type* s, std::streamsize count );`

Comment: What is `inFile`'s type?

Comment: `inFile` is a *variable* of some type.  You're asking how *that type's* `Read` function works.  We can't give you details about that type without knowing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you think `inFile.Read` is the name of a function, when it is not. `inFile` is an object, and `Read` is a member function of `inFile`'s class.

Since you haven't specified the type of `inFile`, there's no way we can tell you what `Read` does. We don't even know if its type is part of an open source library we can view, or whether it is private code belonging to the author of the code you are looking at. Have a look at his code and look at the definition for `Read`.

Comment: That is correct, I managed to trace it back to a function written by the source author and not a std method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I thought was a method in the C++ std class was in fact a custom class. I discovered that the signature was bool Read (size_t itemSize, int numItems, void* data); Thanks.